# Use Darboux’s Theorem to prove a function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-verification

Deﬁne a function by
\begin{equation*}
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x,&x<1\\
x-1, &x\geq 1.
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Prove that there does not exist a function $f(x)$ that is diﬀerentiable on all of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$. 
And my instructor requires us to use Darboux’s Theorem to prove this question.

Could someone help me to figure it out? I'd appreciate it!

Comment: "f(x)=g(x)"? Why don't you just say "g(x) is not differentiable on all of $\Bbb R$"?

Comment: Did you mean f'(x) = g(x)?

Comment: yes,I mean f'(x) = g(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume, for a contradiction, there exists such a function $f(x)$ everywhere-differentiable on $\Bbb R$ satisfying $f'(x) = g(x)$.

Since $g(x)$ is the derivative of $f(x)$, Darboux's theorem states that the image of an interval under $g$ is also an interval.

However, $g([0.5,1]) = [0,0] \cup [0.5,1)$ which is not an interval.

Hence, a contradiction is reached.

Comment: could you tell me what is the meaning of  g([0.5,1])=[0,0]∪[0.5,1)?Thanks

Comment: @YUANFENG The image of $[0.5,1]$ under $g$ is $\{0\} \cup [0.5,1)$

Comment: okay!I got it!Thanks